# my previously stored data in memory(in the form of json) is corrupting on app update, why? and how?

Tags: android, json, gson

My `JSON`, before app update and without updating from previous version is same and i.e. :

```
 {
  "my_activites": 19,
  "age": "",
  "description": "It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.",
  "id": 90,
  "name": "The College Tour",
  "pdfUrl": "",
  "total_pages": 1
}
```

And the `JSON` I am getting after app update is like:

```
{
  "ain": 1,
  "ajW": 19,
  "aki": "",
  "akp": "",
  "description": "It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.",
  "id": 90,
  "name": "The College Tour"
}
```

I am using `GSON` library version `2.8.0` for creating `JSON` in string
 form- from my model class, compile tool 22 and build tool 26.0.2.
 And storing this `JSON` string in shared preference object and same in
 `sqlite` also. On both the places my `JSON` is corrupting only when I
 update the app. Otherwise my app is running smooth and data is not
 changing its form. Can anyone please tell me why it is happening?

I am using android studio 3.0.1

Comment: how are you updating the app ? from playstore? @Neha

Comment: As some data in your json remained untouched, seems that you are some problem in your model , maybe some how you changed the `@serialized` values of your class fields or something like this.

Comment: @Santanu Sur , either I update it from play store or from apk in both case the data is changing.

Comment: @Merka , for serializing the model I am using Parcelable and I have checked there and the model has no problem. But how can any problem in model would only effect the update case of app?..please guide me!

Comment: @Neha I mean the annotation with tag `@SerializedName` as described here : https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-24 that you can use with your model in `gson` so as `gson` use the name used in annotation as the name of the field when it generates json. Maybe in your update you some how or by mistake has altered the name that you can give to fields with this tag.

Answer (score 0):

The problem because you're using Parcelable for persisting the data.
You need to persist the data as Serializable object. Parcelable is only for high-performance data transport.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles.html):

> Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism, and you
>   should never store any Parcel data on disk or send it over the
>   network.